# How to fix the fatal errors while initializing WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

- I am getting a fatal error when starting WSO2 ESB 5.0.0.
- Earlier I got database in use error which was resolved by deleting
  `lock.db` file.
- I tried removing the `.car` file from `repository/server/carbonapps`.
  But it didn't solve the issue either.
- Search on `WstxEOFException` didn't help either.

This is a development setup so re-install may work but I wanted to fix the issue the right way. Any suggestion/direction would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

```
    [2016-11-28 15:59:20,657] FATAL - CarbonServerManager WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected end of input block in comment
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [455,80]
        at com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException.throwLazily(WstxLazyException.java:45)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwLazyError(StreamScanner.java:720)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3677)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getText(BasicStreamReader.java:858)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.createComment(StAXOMBuilder.java:476)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:279)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:595)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:575)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:341)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:192)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected end of input block in comment
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [455,80]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOB(StreamScanner.java:691)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMoreFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:1063)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNextCharFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:802)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readComment2(BasicStreamReader.java:3857)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readComment(BasicStreamReader.java:3843)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.finishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3742)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3675)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: Looks like axis2.xml parsing failed. make sure it's a valid xml. Did you change anything in it?